# 'loose' cells on top tabular

Tags: tables

I'm trying to create this table I've made in Word, but I can't seem to get those top two cells. Is there a way to create this table?

[image: Word table]
Here's what I have so far:

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{| p{3cm} | p{1cm} | p{1cm} | p{1cm} | p{4cm} | p{1cm} | p{1cm} | p{1cm} |}
    \hline
     1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
    \hline
     1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To achieve this you can use `\cline` for the horizontal rules that shouldn't cover all columns, and `\multicolumn` to override the definition of the columns you don't want to have vertical rules, and those you want to join together.

A short note on the calculation of the width of the joined cells: We add together the single widths of the joined cells, but the actual width will be larger, what's missing is the padding added to each side of a column (3 columns means 6 paddings of width `\tabcolsep`, minus 2 for the new column -> `4\tabcolsep`). Now, if you don't load the `array` package the vertical rules of a table don't take up any space and we're done. But as soon as `array` is loaded that is changed. So if, *and only if*, `array` got loaded you'd have to also add `\arrayrulewidth` for each vertical rule which would be otherwise between your joined columns (so in this case `2\arrayrulewidth` would need to be added if `array` got loaded).

The following doesn't load `array` so the `2\arrayrulewidth` are omitted.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| p{3cm} | p{1cm} | p{1cm} | p{1cm} | 
                  p{4cm} | p{1cm} | p{1cm} | p{1cm} |}
  \cline{2-4}
  \cline{6-8}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 
  \multicolumn{3}{|p{\dimexpr3cm+4\tabcolsep\relax}|}{aaa}
  & & 
  \multicolumn{3}{|p{\dimexpr3cm+4\tabcolsep\relax}|}{bbb} \\
  \hline
   1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
  \hline
   1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You had better watch out, @Mico.  You keep this demand for precision up, and someone might accidentally confuse you for Ulrich.

Comment: Thank you all for the answer! Now I'm trying to center the text in the cell saying 'aaa' and '2', how do I do this?

Comment: @Jaap To get the `aaa` centered, change the `\multicolumn` for the `aaa` cell from a `p{...}` specification to a `c` column, as in `\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{aaa}`.  To get `2` centered, *while retaining the 1cm column width*, the easiest thing to do would be to change the `2` to `\centering 2`.

Answer (score 11):

With `tabularray` you will not have problems with calculation of multi column cells width:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{hline{2-Z} = {1-Z}{solid},
             vline{2-Z} = {1-Z}{solid},
             vline{1} = {2-Z}{solid},
             colspec  = {Q[wd=3cm,l] *{3}{Q[wd=1cm,l]} Q[wd=4cm,l] *{3}{Q[wd=1cm,l]}},
             row{Z} = {bg=gray9},             }
  \cline{2-4}
  \cline{6-8}
    & \SetCell[c=3]{l}  
        &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{l}  
                        &   &   \\  
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The fact you can do it in Word doesn’t mean it should be replicated…

Anyway, you shouldn’t use `p` columns for this application, but rather `w` columns (the `array` package is needed).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newlength{\tunit}
\setlength{\tunit}{0.5cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
 | w{l}{3\tunit} |
   w{c}{1\tunit} |
   w{c}{1\tunit} |
   w{c}{1\tunit} |
   w{l}{4\tunit} |
   w{c}{1\tunit} |
   w{c}{1\tunit} |
   w{c}{1\tunit} |
}
\cline{2-4} \cline{6-8}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{aaa} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{bbb} \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note that no calculation is necessary. I just introduced a parameter for the length, because 13 cm is way too big.

[image]

You can modify the cell alignments as you prefer.

Answer (score 5):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}
  [first-row,hvlines]
  {w{l}{15mm}w{c}{5mm}w{c}{5mm}w{c}{5mm}w{l}{20mm}w{c}{5mm}w{c}{5mm}w{c}{5mm}}
& \Block[draw]{1-3}{aaa} &&&& \Block[draw]{1-3}{bbb} \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]